My USB Shown as No Media - How Do I Fix it? And Get My Data
I am unable to see my files because USB shown no media found. What to I do?

Sorry, there really isn't anything to go on here, and it sounds more like a hardware failure than an Ubuntu issue. Can you see the USB contents on another computer? Please try and include more details in your question.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
Or did you overwrite the first bytes of the disk, where the shape of the disk is described?

More details would help.  Last week I had a thumb drive with the same result.  In my case, it had been working until I bumped it while it was writing.  After bumping it, it showed no media.  I tried again and then again on a different Ubuntu and finally on an XP system - all with the same result.  A thumb drive that responds no media is no longer viable.
Use thumb drives with the expectation that they are likely to fail suddenly and completely on an individual basis. Important files can be stored on USB thumb drives if that data is stored somewhere else, probably on another USB thumb drive.  The risk of a USB drive failure is too high to risk important data.  The risk of multiple USB drive failures in a short time is MUCH lower.
